# How do I check if an <s:message /> has been set in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I have the following two files (JSF 1.2) to build a form:

```
<!-- segment of form.xhtml -->
<s:decorate template="edit.xhtml">
    <h:inputText label="First Name" id="firstName" required="true" value="#{contactBean.firstName}">
        <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="25"/>
    </h:inputText>
</s:decorate>

<!-- segment of edit.xhtml -->
<s:validateAll>
    <ui:insert />
</s:validateAll>

<h:graphicImage value="/images/errorIcon.png" rendered="#{when we have a message for this input}" />
<s:message />
```

**In `edit.xhtml`, is there an expression I use in the `<h:graphicImage>` `rendered` attribute?**

I tried `rendered="#{invalid}"`, but the `invalid` remains true even after the `<s:messages />` are cleared. This results in the `errorIcon.png` being displayed without an associated `<s:message />`.

Let me know if I'm taking entirely the wrong approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about the Seam part, I'll only suggest the generic JSF approach. I see basically two ways to achieve this requirement:

1. Wrap [`FacesContext#getMessages(String clientId)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getMessages%28java.lang.String%29) in a bean property.

   ```
   public boolean hasMessages(String clientId) {
       return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessages(clientId).hasNext();
   }
   ```

   Use it as follows:

   ```
   <h:graphicImage rendered="#{bean.hasMessages('form:firstName')}" />
   ```

   *(I assume that you're already using JBoss EL)*
2. Set the image as CSS background image instead (my preferred approach):

   ```
   <s:message errorClass="message error" />
   ```

   with

   ```
   .message.error {
       background: url('error.png') no-repeat left center;
       padding-left: 15px;
   }
   ```

Comment: I definitely like the second approach better than what I was aiming for, thanks.

Comment: @balusc, Is there a chance of including similar method in the utility class Messages Omnifaces project?