# JSF : Better way to check for existence of <h:message for="id"/>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a form in which validation error message needs to be displayed below the input elements. The error needs to be highlighted by showing an error bubble around the error message and the input text.

To achieve this, I need to check for the existence of h:messages for individual elements. 
I am able to check for the existence of global error messages as follows

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty facesContext.messages}"> 
</h:panelGroup>
```

How I can check the same for specific client id (say first name). So something like

```
faceContent.messages("creditCardNo")
```

A solution I have currently is to create a custom resolver but was wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> *The error needs to be highlighted by showing an error bubble around the error message ...*

Just use `<h:message>` with a styleclass wherein you define the desired style.

```xml
<h:inputText id="foo" />
<h:message for="foo" styleClass="error" />
```

with

```css
.error {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: pink;
}
```

---

> *...and the input text.*

Just check if [`UIInput#isValid()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uiinput#isValid--) is `true`. Since JSF 2.0 the current component is available by implicit EL variable `#{component}`.

```xml
<h:inputText styleClass="#{component.valid ? 'none' : 'error'}" />
```

---

As to the *actual* question about checking if there's a message for a certain client ID, then you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442366/how-do-i-check-if-an-smessage-has-been-set-in-jsf/4443353#4443353) interesting. But I don't think that this is applicable in your particular case.

---

**Update**: as per the comments, you seem to want to style the containing component instead of the invididual components. In that case, do as follows:

```xml
<h:panelGroup styleClass="#{foo.valid ? 'none' : 'error'}">
    <h:inputText id="foo" binding="#{foo}" />
    <h:message for="foo" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out component.valid in JSF2.0. I can use this else where in my code. However, I need to display the error bubble around the label name and the input box. Whereas <h:inputText styleClass="#{!component.valid ? 'error' : 'none'}" /> will just get me the error bubble around the input box

Answer (score 0):

I use bootstrap and also needed this... solved it by creating a Custom component wrapper.

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="casoCustomFieldValue" required="true" />
    <composite:attribute name="casoOpen" default="true" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

    <h:panelGroup styleClass="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList(''.concat(cc.clientId).concat(':valortext')) ? 'form-group has-error' : 'form-group'}"
                  rendered="#{cc.attrs.casoCustomFieldValue.customField.fieldTypeId.fieldTypeId eq 'TEXT'}" >
        <p:inputText id="valortext" value="#{cc.attrs.casoCustomFieldValue.valor}" styleClass="form-control input-sm"
                 required="#{cc.attrs.casoCustomFieldValue.customField.required}" requiredMessage="Se necesita un valor." disabled="#{not cc.attrs.casoOpen}"/>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList(''.concat(cc.clientId).concat(':valortext'))}" styleClass="help-block">
            <h:message for="valortext" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>



</composite:implementation>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator<FacesMessage> pkit = fctxt.getMessages(); // check all existing messages from the FacesContext         
while(pkit.hasNext()){ 
    System.out.println(pkit.next().getDetail()); // get message text
    System.out.println(pkit.next().getSummary());
}
```

If the message you are looking for is found in the while loop, you can take appropriate action

Comment: Taking the appropriate action is the challenge here. How/what would you do?