# Possible to set the styleClass of a xp:control from validator class?

Tags: jsf, xpages

For a form I have set up a validaor for an Edit Box e.g.:

```
<xp:inputText
    id="inpRiskFactors" 
    styleClass="inputEscalation"
    value="#{matterBean.matter.escRiskFactors}" 
    validator="#{matterValidators.valEscRiskFactors}"...
```

Here is a snippet from my validating method:

```
public void valEscRiskFactors(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {        
        utils.printToConsole(this.getClass().getSimpleName().toString() + " - valEscRiskFactors(...), value = " + value.toString());
        String msg = null;
        if (value.toString().replaceAll("\\s+","").equals("")){
            msg = matterProp.getProperty("msg_valid_esc_risk_factors");
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(msg);
            throw new ValidatorException(message);
        }       
    }
```

I was wondering if I could change/set the styleclass property of the calling component (UIComponent component) from this method?

For the user it would be nice to apply some CSS on the xp:controls that are required and do not pass the validation.

Anyone have a clue how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explicit call to `setStyleClass` method of `UIComponent` casted to `XspInputText` works for me

```java
((XspInputText)component).setStyleClass("my-class");
```

If you don't want to cast but want to apply the `styleClass` to any component that supports such property, java reflection can help:

```java
try {
    Method setStyleClass = component.getClass().getMethod("setStyleClass", String.class);
    if (setStyleClass != null) {
        setStyleClass.invoke(component, "my-class");
    }
} catch (SecurityException e) {} 
catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {}
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
catch (InvocationTargetException e) {}
```

You may want to append the styleClass instead of replace

```java
try {
    String styleClass = null;
    Method getStyleClass = component.getClass().getMethod("getStyleClass");
    if (getStyleClass != null) {
        styleClass = (String)getStyleClass.invoke(component, (Object[])null);
    }
    Method setStyleClass = component.getClass().getMethod("setStyleClass", String.class);
    if (setStyleClass != null) {
        String newStyleClass = StringUtil.isNotEmpty(styleClass) ? styleClass.concat(" my-class") : "my-class";
        setStyleClass.invoke(component, newStyleClass);
    }
} catch (SecurityException e) {} 
catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {}
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
catch (InvocationTargetException e) {}
```

Answer (score 5):

Most (all?) standard XPages controls uses the [WAI-ARIA standard for validation](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-1.1/states_and_properties) and therefore automatically gets the `aria-invalid` property set to "true" when the control is invalid.

This means that you can use CSS to style the input control. You can for instance style the background-color and border differently when the control is invalid:

```
[aria-invalid=true] {
    background-color: #fee;
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I like the simplicity :-)

Comment: And if this for one reason or another does not work, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727666/conditional-style-in-jsf-when-validation-has-failed-in-general